# I upgraded to "Xcode 11 Beta 3" which only pulls in "Create ML" (version 1), no "activity" classifier model shown?

Tags: xcode, createml

Only "Image", "Sound", and "Text" Models shown in Create ML?

I looked on developer.apple.com website but do not see where I can download or upgrade from the current version "1.0" of "Create ML", without having to download "Xcode 11 Beta 3" again (which is what I already did and this only provided version 1)?

N/A - code section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be running the macOS Catalina beta. Then it will show up among the Xcode developer tools.

Comment: No, I am running Catalina Beta (10.15), that was a requirement before I could even install Xcode 11 Beta.